# Topological relation between Complex numbers and R^2

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Topologically,are the space of complex numbers and the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^2$ (with the standard topologies) the same?

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: A topological space is a set and a set of subsets. The set of complex numbers does not refer to a topology, it is a set. One can form different topologies from the same set.

Comment: Right.So when complex numbers are treated topologically without explicitly mentioning the topology,we assume an open disc to be a basis element,right?

Comment: Usually I'd say yes. At any rate they can trivially be made to be as R^2 is as a set of ordered pairs and C is ... the exact same set of ordered pairs.  Of course, the cautious mathematician is loathe to say yes they are the same as topologies are not inherent in sets and we don't want to give the impression they are.

Comment: It is standard to consider the metric topologies on these spaces when no other topology is mentioned. Nevertheless I would recommend starting your post by stating that these are the topologies in question when posting on MSE, to avoid needless questioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R^2$ given by 
$$f(x+iy)=(x,y)$$
is a homeomorphism.